# Частично не переведены действия с ревизиями

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, ревизии

[image: скриншот]

```
Источник
Править
Edit comment
Откат
Link
Redact
```

UPDATE:

[image: скриншот кнопки]

```
Update revision comment
```

Comment: у меня нету `Edit comment` и `Redact`. Это только у модераторов?

Comment: @Danis, да, эти два модераторские, а вот `Link` по идее у всех?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я вижу Link

Comment: @AK вам за заслуги перед SOтечеством оставили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновил переводы.

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16081
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16085
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16089

Будет на сайте в новых версиях. Текущая. rev 2021.2.26.38670

Comment: Можно ещё строку?

Comment: @Qwertiy в каком смысле "можно"? У модераторов есть возможность утверждать строки самостоятельно.

Comment: Так надо ещё перевести)

Comment: @Qwertiy так и переводить могут. А ещё хотелось бы чтобы флаги обрабатывались регулярно, и на Мете в том числе.

Comment: Так я по флагу и зашёл, только вместо него докинул ещё строчку)

Comment: @Qwertiy так других флагов достаточно (долго) висит в ожидании. А перевод добавлен уже.

Comment: Так я отвлёкся) Всё, теперь это последний флаг на мете.

Comment: @Qwertiy аллилуйя!